# NullPointerException getting writabledatabase after adding Fragment

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, fragment

I have been converting my app to use fragments for some added flexability however in doing that, when I try to make updates to the database, I am getting a NullPointerException.

```
03-03 09:26:40.610: E/AndroidRuntime(20613): java.lang.NullPointerException
03-03 09:26:40.610: E/AndroidRuntime(20613):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:224)
03-03 09:26:40.610: E/AndroidRuntime(20613):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.java:164)
```

This is in my Fragment.java in the save.setOnClickListener, onClick

```
db.getWritableDatabase();
                db.addGasLog(new gasLog(pricePerGallonInt, gallonsInt, odometerInt, todayString, fill, commentsString, totalSpent));
```

When I am doing this from my normal NewRecord.java (pre adding fragment) I had no problem adding entries to the db.

Any ideas?

EDIT:  I have read a few things about people opening the connection in the MainActivity.java before opening the fragment, if you need to see code from there let me know.

EDIT2:

This is where I initialize db

```
final MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(mContext);
```

Comment: Please let us know where and how you initialize `db` variable

Comment: All set! - final MySQLiteHelper db = new MySQLiteHelper(mContext);

Comment: Check the value of `db` before you do the method call

Comment: There's no trace of `SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked` in my sdk. Is it a method of `MySQLiteHelper` ?

Comment: That is not a method of my helper.  not sure where its actually coming from.

Answer (score 0):

the fragment was not getting the context correctly.  I had to use `getActivity()` to get the appropriate context.